# DateTime format conversion mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Can someone please let me know how do I convert this datetime format into yyyyMMdd

```
2/28/2017 12:02:04 AM
```

At the output I should get `20170228`

Any advice on this?

Comment: You will need to provide some more information as to what you are trying to do.  Try to include examples of what you have tried already.  Do you need to parse the date as a string and then output it.. or is that a DateTime object already.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the DateTime as an object

```
string formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

If you need to parse the value first.

```
string dateValue = "2/28/2017 12:02:04 AM";
string format = "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateValue, format,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For reference you can find a breakdown of the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Added some more info on the Custom Date and Time Format Strings

Answer (score 1):

**You need to specify the format of the date.**

If you want it for the current time you can try like this :

`string dtime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");`

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have come up with for you:

```
string format = "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
string dateString = "2/28/2017 12:02:04 AM";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
string output = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# 6 or later (VS2015), you can format DateTime objects easily by using string interpolation using a custom format string. The custom format string that you're looking for is `"yyyyMMdd"`.

```
// create your preferred date and time in a new DateTime struct
DateTime yourDateTime = new DateTime(2017, 2, 28, 0, 2, 4);

// format yourDateTime as a string
string yourFormattedDateTime = $"{yourDateTime:yyyyMMdd}";
```

You can read more about interpolated strings at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx, and, as previously mentioned by @Adam Carr, you can find more information on custom date and time format strings at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx